# Honoring a wicked father who has repented - How is he still considered wicked?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, mitzvah, repentance-teshuvah, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

The Shulhan 'Aruch [(Y"D 240:18)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=118) writes that one is obligated to honor his father even if the father is wicked (actually, it says that a Mamzer is obligated, but I believe that the implication is that this applies to everyone - I'll take corrective criticism if someone can offer it). However, the RaM"A notes an opinion that this only applies if the father has repented.

But if the father has repented, how can he still be considered wicked?  I thought we have an obligation to regard a penitent as a righteous person and a prohibition against reminding him of his past wrongdoing(s).

Comment: Probably worth tracing it back to the [Rambam](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e306n.htm#13) and the commentaries thereon.